# Timing Difficulties in Effort to Fade Images In and Out

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to have three images fade in and out one at a time. I think I am pretty close with this code, but it is not working as I expect.

What I am hoping for, is that each image will fade in over 0.5 seconds, then will remain on screen for 2 seconds, then will fade out over 0.5 seconds. Once the third image has faded out, I would like it to stop.

The code below keeps fading out the first image over and over, and I can't seem to get the timing down properly. Any assistance would be great!

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {

    pImageC = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    NSArray *animationArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage 
    imageNamed:@"p_image_a.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"p_image_b.png"],[UIImage 
    imageNamed:@"p_image_c.png"], nil]; //add your images here
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(crossfade) 
    userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [pImageC  setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,367)];
    pImageC.animationImages = animationArray; //mainImageView is   imageview
    pImageC.animationDuration = 2;
    pImageC.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [pImageC startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:pImageC];
}

- (void)crossfade {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
    animations:^{
        pImageC.alpha = !pImageC.alpha;
    }completion:^(BOOL done){
        //
    }];
}
```

Comment: Your pImageC.alpha = !pImageC.alpha; makes no sense. alpha is a float, not a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for crossfade animation

```
- (void)crossfade 
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        self.animationImageView.alpha = 0.0;
    }completion:^(BOOL done){
        [self performAnimationOnView];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            self.animationImageView.alpha = 1.0;
        }completion:^(BOOL done){


        }];


    }];

}
```